# user32.GetAsyncKeyState on python to capture keys and mouseclicks

Tags: python, keyboard, keylogger, mousecapture

```
import time
import ctypes
import threading
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
mouse_clicks = 0
keystrokes = 0
def getKeyPressed():
    global mouse_clicks
    global keystrokes
    for i in range(0,256):
        if user32.GetAsyncKeyState(i):
         #   if not i == 19:
             #   print "pressed %d and st = %d " % (i, user32.GetAsyncKeyState(i))
            if i == 1:
                mouse_clicks += 1
                print "left"
                return time.time()
            elif 32 < i < 127:
                keystrokes += 1
    return None
def pr():
    global mouse_clicks
    global keystrokes
    while True:
        print "mouse = %d and key = %d "% (mouse_clicks, keystrokes)
        time.sleep(1)

th = threading.Thread(target=pr)
th.start()
while True:
    getKeyPressed()
```

**The above code produces multiple click results when pressed once**
how do I get the correct number of keystrokes and clicks by modifying the above program?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Author:@ArmonKashani
#@gameoverblog
#python 3.7
#get key multi proccessing

from ctypes import windll
from time import sleep


class Keyboard:
    KeyCodes = {'LeftMouseButton': '0x01', 'RightMouseButton': '0x02', 'ControlBreak': '0x03',
                'MiddleMouseButton': '0x04',
                'X1MouseButton': '0x05', 'X2MouseButton': '0x06', 'Backspace': '0x08', 'Tab': '0x09',
                'Clear': '0x0c',
                'Enter': '0x0d', 'Pause': '0x13', 'CapsLock': '0x14', 'Escape': '0x1B', 'Space': '0x20',
                'PageUp': '0x21',
                'PageDown': '0x22', 'End': '0x23', 'Home': '0x24', 'LeftArrow': '0x25',
                'UpArrow': '0x26',
                'RightArrow': '0x27',
                'DownArrow': '0x28', 'Select': '0x29', 'Print': '0x2a', 'Execute': '0x2b',
                'PrintScreen': '0x2c',
                'Ins': '0x2d',
                'Delete': '0x2e', 'Help': '0x2f', 'Key0': '0x30', 'Key1': '0x31', 'Key2': '0x32',
                'Key3': '0x33',
                'Key4': '0x34',
                'Key5': '0x35', 'Key6': '0x36', 'Key7': '0x37', 'Key8': '0x38', 'Key9': '0x39',
                'A': '0x41',
                'B': '0x42',
                'C': '0x43', 'D': '0x44', 'E': '0x45', 'F': '0x46', 'G': '0x47', 'H': '0x48',
                'I': '0x49',
                'J': '0x4a',
                'K': '0x4b', 'L': '0x4c', 'M': '0x4d', 'N': '0x4e', 'O': '0x4f', 'P': '0x50',
                'Q': '0x51',
                'R': '0x52',
                'S': '0x53', 'T': '0x54', 'U': '0x55', 'V': '0x56', 'W': '0x57', 'X': '0x58',
                'Y': '0x59',
                'LeftWindowsKey': '0x5b', 'RightWindowsKey': '0x5c', 'Application': '0x5d',
                'Sleep': '0x5f',
                'NumpadKey0': '0x60',
                'NumpadKey1': '0x61', 'NumpadKey2': '0x62', 'NumpadKey3': '0x63', 'NumpadKey4': '0x64',
                'NumpadKey5': '0x65',
                'NumpadKey6': '0x66', 'NumpadKey7': '0x67', 'NumpadKey8': '0x68', 'NumpadKey9': '0x69',
                'Multiply': '0x6a',
                'Add': '0x6b', 'Separator': '0x6c', 'Subtract': '0x6d', 'Decimal': '0x6e',
                'Divide': '0x6f',
                'F1': '0x70',
                'F2': '0x71', 'F3': '0x72', 'F4': '0x73', 'F5': '0x74', 'F6': '0x75', 'F7': '0x76',
                'F8': '0x77',
                'F9': '0x78',
                'F10': '0x79', 'F11': '0x7a', 'F12': '0x7b', 'F13': '0x7c', 'F14': '0x7d',
                'F15': '0x7e',
                'F16': '0x7f',
                'F17': '0x80', 'F18': '0x81', 'F19': '0x82', 'F20': '0x83', 'F21': '0x84',
                'F22': '0x85',
                'F23': '0x86',
                'F24': '0x87', 'NumLock': '0x90', 'ScrollLock': '0x91', 'LeftShift': '0xa0',
                'RightShift': '0xa1',
                'LeftControl': '0xa2', 'RightControl': '0xa3', 'LeftMenu': '0xa4', 'RightMenu': '0xa5',
                'BrowserBack': '0xa6',
                'BrowserRefresh': '0xa8', 'BrowserStop': '0xa9', 'BrowserSearch': '0xaa',
                'BrowserFavorites': '0xab',
                'BrowserHome': '0xac', 'VolumeMute': '0xad', 'VolumeDown': '0xae', 'VolumeUp': '0xaf',
                'NextTrack': '0xb0',
                'PreviousTrack': '0xb1', 'StopMedia': '0xb2', 'PlayMedia': '0xb3',
                'StartMailKey': '0xb4',
                'SelectMedia': '0xb5',
                'StartApplication1': '0xb6', 'StartApplication2': '0xb7'}

    GetAsyncKeyState = windll.User32.GetAsyncKeyState

    @staticmethod
    def GetKey():
        for keyName, keyNum in Keyboard.KeyCodes.items():
            keyN = int(keyNum, 16)
            if Keyboard.GetAsyncKeyState(keyN) != 0:
                while Keyboard.GetAsyncKeyState(keyN) != 0:
                    sleep(0.001)
                return keyName
        return None
#while Keyboard.GetKey()!LeftMouseButton':pass
while Keyboard.GetKey()!='P':
  print('salam')
print('p pressed')
```